# How to create a formula that will create borders over multiple rows with the same value in Column A

Tags: excel-formula

I need to group rows together with borders based on the value in the first column. These groups can vary between 1-10 rows. I'm hoping to create a formula that works in the following logic:

1 Select row 
2 Check if next row has the same value in column A
3 If next row has the same value, also select next row (do this until the next row has a different value)
4 If next row has a different value, create a border out of the previously selected rows
5 Select next row and start over at step 2

Comment: Formulas cannot change the format of a cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner I see...so if this can't be achieved with formulas, is there another option?

Comment: Conditional formatting will probably be your best bet.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ok. So I can see that I can format them to add borders. I just can't wrap my head around the formula for the conditional formatting. The solutions that I have found only work with single rows

Answer (score 0):

The formula to test if the value in the second row is different to the value in the first row is

```
=A2<>A3
```

If you want to use this rule across a range, you need to use **absolute reference** for column A, hence

```
=$A2<>$A3
```

Presume you have a 4-Column table, and you want to use the above rule to highlight rows where the value in column A is different to the next value in column A, you need to set up **three** conditional formatting as shown below.

Please note Column E is for demonstration only and you do not need to create this helper column at all.

[image: Conditional Formatting]

It would be a tedious work when you want to use conditional formatting across a range of data instead of a single column. In your case, you will need to set a format for the beginning column of the range, set another format for all columns in between, and set another format for the last column of the range.

Hope this answer your question. Cheers :)